# How to integrate a react js project(client) and node js(Middle ware) project into one project and publish to azure web application

Tags: node.js, reactjs, azure, deployment, integration

I'm working on a project for which we are using React in frontend, NodeJS(GraphQL) in middleware and C# in backend.

I'm trying to deploy the integrated app (Currently, React and GraphQL are two independent projects, I want to integrate them into one project) in azure web services.

1) Copied all files from React and GraphQL projects into a new folder (client)

2) Ran Build, application so bundle.js and index.html is created.

3) Referenced above files in package.json but unable to open HTML pages.

```
import express from 'express'
import graphQLHTTP from 'express-graphql'
import cors from 'cors'
import path from 'path'

import schema from './src/Schema'

let app = express()

app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'ProjectName','dist')))

app.get('/',function(request,response){
  response.sendFile(path.join(__dirname,'ProjectName','dist','index.html'))
})

app.use('/Project',graphQLHTTP({`
  schema,
  graphiql: true
`})
)

const port = process.env.PORT || 1337
app.listen(port)
```

I want to integrate both applications to one and deploy to azure web application.